# Spring Rest and Thread Pool

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest

We are creating logging mechanism for restful services in Spring. The thing is that every request in spring  is a new thread. My question is: everytime new thread is created or maybe thread are taking form thread pool ? Thanks for answer.

Comment: It isn't a new thread. Request are handled by a thread pool (and it has nothing to do with Spring but how your servlet container works).

Comment: if you r not handling any multithreading at your code level, than it all depends on server and servelt container.